# How can I get my PHP script to load after jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Surprisingly I cannot find anyone else having this issue, which means I am doing something wrong.  From what I understand, PHP is read first, by the browser, correct?

I am using jQuery UI to display a tabbed view, like so:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
</script>
```

Very simple...
Inside of the tabbed view I have a lengthy bit of PHP code that grabs the system status information from a server and displays this information inside of one of the tabs, called 'system status', like so:

```
                   <div id="tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#tabs-1">System Status</a></li>

                        </ul>
                        <div id="tabs-1">
                            <?php //Lengthy PHP script ?>
                    </div>
```

Normally PHP loads so fast that you cannot tell that the PHP is being loaded before the jQuery UI tab is being loaded.  In this case, you will see some text being displayed as the browser loads the PHP script and fetches server-side info before the UI is loaded and it causes my GUI to look really nasty.

I have googled this issue and cannot figure out how to simply force the jQuery to code to execute BEFORE the PHP code, so that you will see my nice tabbed UI first while the PHP code executes within it.  Any help or point in the right direction would be great.  Oh, and I am also great at getting schooled and slapped in the face with hard computer science if I am completely missing something important here.  Thank you.

Comment: PHP is processed on the server first, and the resulting HTML is delivered to the client, at which point your JavaScript is processed. You probably want to check out an AJAX solution.

Comment: You misunderstood, PHP is executed on the server side, the browser never even sees PHP. You might need to do an AJAX request if you want this deferred loading.

Comment: The PHP is executed on the server ***before*** the page is even sent to the browser, so you can't execute PHP code after javascript, with the exception of Ajax.

Comment: php has completely finished before one byte is sent to the browser by the server

Comment: Yes, you can make an ajax call after the tabs are there calling your php file to render the html content you need there, for the purposes of this exercise. Best practice is though (where deferred loading is not neccessary), to actually get the content, then manipulate the DOM with JS, tabs etc.

Comment: @Dagon that is not always the case. You *can* use output buffering and some crafted headers to push packets of data to the client in fragments while the script lives on. I grant that it isn't a typical scenario, but your statement struck me as too absolute.

Comment: Oh, and to Mac (the OP) -- please ignore my sidebar discussion. You have some learning to do about the fundamentals before you worry about this kind of nitpicking :) For your purposes, Dagon is 100% correct!

Comment: I am still amazed how fast I receive helpful comments on SO.  Thanks a lot people.  I now understand things a bit more clearly.  I'll look into AJAX as a solution, but for now I going with the display:none css class.

Comment: @Chris, answers tailored to question, may not always be 100% 'accurate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your tabs content a class e.g `content` and in css make it `display:none`

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="content">
```

So the text being displayed as the browser loads the PHP script will not be visible and when the tabs will be loaded you will see the content of current tab by default

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/1152/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Ui tabs, support the calls with Ajax.
So, you need another page or controller with the data that you want to show.

In the official page is better explained.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Believe, is more easier than you think.